# Not able to use max and sum functions in Pig

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I am trying to run a query to find the max of a column of double type and it give me this error

> Could not Infer the matching function for org.apache.builtin.MAX as
>   multiple or none of them fit . Please use am explicit cast.

And my structure for the data is as following:

```
maxtest: {name: chararray, value: double}
```

Comment: show us what u have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the exception I can tell you that you are not passing expected data type to the MAX function. It supposed to be numeric type, please check and try again with new data type for that column.